# Centos what can non root user damage?

Tags: linux

How much harm can a non-root user cause other than filling the disk with files

i mean what he can do to damage the server or destroy other users files?

--

and gcc and g++ are disabled on the server

thanks

Comment: Absent an unpatched or zero-day exploit, or misconfigured protections, not much.  Filling up `/tmp` will annoy a few things, I guess.

Comment: thanks for reply .. i said other than filling /tmp what he can do?

Comment: I just told you.  I'd add fork bombs, which could use up all the VM and cause the OOM killer to wake up, if you don't have limits on memory usage.

Comment: so just hang the system .. no harm or corruption for other users files

Comment: If you assume that there is always unknown an unpatched bugs on every system, then the answer is potentially a lot of harm.  This question probalby isn't going to get useful answers.  Most people just assume the is a potential for harm and setup backups, resource monitoring, and other system to notify when bad things happen.

Comment: Mostly denial of service. How about, binding to every TCP port above 1024, but not connecting anywhere. This 'reserves' the port and prevents other genuine uses for the TCP address. That can cause all sorts of havoc when connections out want to be created. Fork bombs can be limited by resource limits, TCP consumption cannot since open file limits apply per process (you could fork loads). Only straight forward way to protect about this is to shove users into separate namespaces which is rather over-engineering an answer.

Comment: i was talking about reading files of other users while compilers are OFF that all i need

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you call harm. Non-privileged users can read more than I care for, often. Home directories are often world-readable, for instance. For Debian based systems, you can configure a default for that in `/etc/adduser.conf`.

If there are hosted websites, they can read config files (unless protected), containing passwords to databases, etc.

And as you say, they can fill the disk, thrash the disk, fill memory, fork-bomb to crash the server possibly (check output of `ulimit -a`) (madhatter just beat me to that comment...)

Perhaps tell us what you're about to do, and what you need to prevent.

Comment: im trying to read other users files or modifying them

Comment: im in cetos system and permission denied for reading those directories

Comment: Your _goal_ is to read/write other users files? Is the server patched for 'Dirty COW'? Try that...

Comment: how to test Dirty COW and compilers are OFF permission denied as i told above